# Sandwich Conditions in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying the following condition, the compiler give no warning but the code does not seems to work. Should This work?

```
if (self.finishLine > hero.position.y > self.startHeight)
{
     hero.position  = CGPointMake( hero.position.x + translation.x,  hero.position.y);
}
```

Comment: Remember that Objective-C is based on C, so an aspect like this one is not specific to Objective-C (as your title suggests), but a simple question of how boolean expressions can be written in C.

Comment: I know but you have for example the forin statement in objective-c that does not exist in c afaik.

Comment: Sure, but the topic here is boolean expressions (for-in is not an expression but a control statement). The finer details of language syntax are a bit above my station, though, so I'll leave it at this.

Comment: Ah, re-reading your question, and commenting on my own comment above, I see that you consider it a condition-construct. It is not - as mentioned by Hermann, it is a simple boolean expression which happens to be used to evaluate an if statement. You could write the same expression as a right hand side of a boolean assignment statement. You'd probably think that looks wrong in C, and hence it looks wrong inside an if-statement, too.

Answer (score 2):

Comparison operators return boolean values.

(self.finishLine > hero.position.y > self.startHeight)

-> ((self.finishLine > hero.position.y) > self.startHeight)

-> ((<0 or 1> > self.startHeight)

I doubt that self.startHeight is ever less than 1, let alone less than 0.

The correct form in C is:

((self.finishLine > hero.position.y) && (hero.position.y > self.startHeight))

Comment: yes I resolved my self to write the condition that way. It could have been cool to have sandwich condition

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it but I believe it is a valid expression. AFAIK Objective C does not support sandwiches..

(a > b > c) should evaluate to TRUE or FALSE respectively YES or NO. But how? The compiler would start from left to right here as all operators are equal. (a > b) will evaluate to YES or NO. Those are internally represented by 1 and 0. 1 and 0 may be larger than c or not.

I wonder if the compiler throws a warning at least.

Did you go for it and tried it?

Comment: ha you think it will turn self.finishLine > hero.position.y to 1 or 0 and then compare 1 or 0 > self.startHeight ? I would love a pastrami sandwich btw...